# Sorting the alphanumeric values of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dictionary in python which is like below:
In this scenario my dictionary has 'ESPN' and 'AAA' are the keys and values are below

```
'ESPN': [
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_1050',
    'ESPN 60 TO 70_1150',
    'ESPN 80 TO 90_1250',
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_1750',
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_900'
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_1650',
    'ESPN 70 TO 80_1350',
    'ESPN 20 TO 30_1450'
]

'AAA': [
    'AAA 90 TO 100_1050',
    'AAA 60 TO 70_1150',
    'AAA 80 TO 90_1250',
    'AAA 90 TO 100_1750',
    'AAA 90 TO 100_1650',
    'AAA 70 TO 80_1350',
    'AAA 20 TO 30_1450'
]
```

I am trying to sort this dictionary in such a way that i want the number after the ESPN and AAA in ascending way and also the number after the underscore.

For example like below

```
'ESPN': [
    'ESPN 20 TO 30_1450',
    'ESPN 60 TO 70_1150',
    'ESPN 70 TO 80_1350',
    'ESPN 80 TO 90_1250',
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_900',
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_1650',
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_1750',
]
```

I am trying regex and sort but i am not able to get it. Would really appreciate if someone could help. I also tried various sorting techniques but i always end up sorting the keys and not the values.
Also in most scenarios its not working as expected as when i am having a value as AAA 20 to 30_900 it is not coming in order before AAA 20 TO 30_1450 but after it.

TIA

Comment: Could you please clarify, what the keys and what the values are and what do you want to sort? Am I right that you hae a dict with e.g. 'ESPN' and 'AAA' as keys and their values are lists and these lists should be sorted?

Comment: What do you mean by "and also the number after the underscore"?

Comment: I am trying to sort the values of this dict with numbers starting after 'ESPN ' in ascending order and for instance if 'ESPN 90 TO 100_1650'
    'ESPN 90 TO 100_1750' are present ESPN 90 to 100_1650 should come first as the number 1650 after the '_' which also i meant in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` to extract all contiguous sequences of digits, convert to integers and apply a lexicographic sort.

```
key = lambda s: tuple(map(int, re.findall('\d+', s)))
result = {k: sorted(v, key=key) for k, v in data.items()}

# Output

In [156]: result
Out[156]: 
{'AAA': ['AAA 20 TO 30_1450',
  'AAA 60 TO 70_1150',
  'AAA 70 TO 80_1350',
  'AAA 80 TO 90_1250',
  'AAA 90 TO 100_1050',
  'AAA 90 TO 100_1650',
  'AAA 90 TO 100_1750'],
 'ESPN': ['ESPN 20 TO 30_1450',
  'ESPN 60 TO 70_1150',
  'ESPN 70 TO 80_1350',
  'ESPN 80 TO 90_1250',
  'ESPN 90 TO 100_900',
  'ESPN 90 TO 100_1050',
  'ESPN 90 TO 100_1650',
  'ESPN 90 TO 100_1750']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using successive `str.split` calls. Mapping to integers ensures that 900 will come before 1000.

```
def sorter(x):
    _, var1, _, var2 = x.split()
    var2a, var2b = var2.split('_')
    return list(map(int, (var1, var2a, var2b)))

res = sorted(d['ESPN'], key=sorter)

['ESPN 20 TO 30_1450',
 'ESPN 60 TO 70_1150',
 'ESPN 70 TO 80_1350',
 'ESPN 80 TO 90_1250',
 'ESPN 90 TO 100_900',
 'ESPN 90 TO 100_1050',
 'ESPN 90 TO 100_1650',
 'ESPN 90 TO 100_1750']
```

Comment: I actually tried something like this and the problem here is i cannot specify all the keys each time to get sorted and i also want the sorted order in a dictionary with the key retained.

Comment: @apak23, Sorry, I don't understand the issue. If you have different types of data which causes this logic to fail, can you update your question accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
    'ESPN': [
        'ESPN 90 TO 100_1050',
        'ESPN 60 TO 70_1150',
        'ESPN 80 TO 90_1250',
        'ESPN 90 TO 100_1750',
        'ESPN 90 TO 100_1650',
        'ESPN 70 TO 80_1350',
        'ESPN 20 TO 30_1450'
    ],
    'AAA': [
        'AAA 90 TO 100_1050',
        'AAA 60 TO 70_1150',
        'AAA 80 TO 90_1250',
        'AAA 90 TO 100_1750',
        'AAA 90 TO 100_1650',
        'AAA 70 TO 80_1350',
        'AAA 20 TO 30_1450'
    ]
}
[v.sort() for v in d.values()]
```

Result:

```
{'AAA': ['AAA 20 TO 30_1450',
  'AAA 60 TO 70_1150',
  'AAA 70 TO 80_1350',
  'AAA 80 TO 90_1250',
  'AAA 90 TO 100_1050',
  'AAA 90 TO 100_1650',
  'AAA 90 TO 100_1750'],
 'ESPN': ['ESPN 20 TO 30_1450',
  'ESPN 60 TO 70_1150',
  'ESPN 70 TO 80_1350',
  'ESPN 80 TO 90_1250',
  'ESPN 90 TO 100_1050',
  'ESPN 90 TO 100_1650',
  'ESPN 90 TO 100_1750']}
```

Comment: This works perfect in most scenarios but its not working as expected but when i am having a value as AAA 20 to 30_900 it is not coming in order before AAA 20 TO 30_1450 but after it.

Comment: Okay I see.  Then one of the other answers that uses regular expressions or `split` is what you need.